# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{nx}{(2n)^2+(kx)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm preparing for my exam and this the last task of past-year tasks: How to solve such limit with function series?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{nx}{(2n)^2+(kx)^2}
$$
It's kindly different from any I've done before and I'm even don't know where to begin.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{nx}{(2n)^{2}+(kx)^{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{nx}{(2n)^{2}+(kx)^{2}}-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{nx}{(2n)^{2}+(kx)^{2}}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{4}\coth\frac{2\pi n}{x}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{8n}\frac{8+x^2}{4+x^2}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)$$

Comment: But $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to rewrite your expression.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{nx}{(2n)^{2}+(kx)^{2}}=x\times\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4+(\frac{k}{n})^{2}x^{2}}
$$
And use the theorem of Riemann's sum

Expo

Comment: (You have to suppose x différent of $0$ to applicate this theorem)

Comment: I can't understand how to apply Riemann's sum to this...

Comment: Well, see that 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4+(\frac{k}{n})^{2}x^{2}}=\frac{1-0}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4+(\frac{k(1-0)}{n})^{2}x^{2}}
$$
 and this converges (for $x \neq 0$) to :
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{4+t^{2}x^{2}}dt
$$
To evaluate this integral you have to do a variable substitution to recognize something like $\frac{1}{1+y^{2}}$

Comment: Where $\frac{1-0}{n}$ comes from?

Comment: Riemann's sums theorem establishes that for $a<b$ and $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function on $[a,b]$ you have :
$$
\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(a+k\frac{b-a}{n} )\xrightarrow[n \rightarrow +\infty]{}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt
$$
Here, $a=0, b=1$ and $\forall t \in [0,1],f(t)=\frac{1}{4+t^{2}x^{2}}$